# Display unicode characters - Android

Tags: java, android, json, unicode

I have a json for currencies :

```
[
  {
    "acronym": "EUR",
    "currency": "Euros",
    "favorite": "true",
    "placeholder": "\\u20ac00.00 EUR",
    "symbol": "\\u20ac"
  }
]
```

I put this in the asset folder and parse like so:

```
InputStream stream = context.getAssets().open("currencies.json");
int size = stream.available();
byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
stream.read(buffer);
stream.close();
str = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
```

which I then convert to my pojo object with GSON

```
Type objectType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Currency>>(){}.getType();
ArrayList<Currency> currencies = gson.fromJson(json, objectType);
return currencies;
```

which works fine (my pojo properties are named the same as in the json).

**HOWEVER**

When I try to display the symbol it doesn't display it as it should, for example
I get "\u20ac" instead of "€"

```
txtAmount.setText(currency.getSymbol());
```

I've tried the following log

```
Log.d(currency.getSymbol() + "\u20ac");
```

Which gives me:

```
\u20ac€
```

I don't understand why it won't display the characters properly..

Comment: Your JSON is escaping the backslash. Try `"\u20ac"` instead of `"\\u20ac"`

Comment: (You're also reading the JSON in a horrible way. You should almost *never* use `available()`. Use an `InputStreamReader`, and ideally use a helper library which can just read the contents of any `Reader` into a string. Guava, for example.)

Comment: @Jon Skeet 
Thanks that was it, could you post a short answer so that I can accept it and give you the credit. 

As for the InputStreamReader, I wasn't able to find a better way to read a file from the assets, I 'll take a look at guava. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON has escaped the backslash, which means it's the JSON representation of "backslash u 20ac".

All you need to do is *not* escape the backslash, so that `\u20ac` is the JSON-escaped version of the Euro symbol:

```
"symbol": "\u20ac"
```

I'd also suggest using Guava to load your string, with a try-with-resources statement:

```
String json;
try (Reader reader = 
         new InputStreamReader(context.getAssets().open("currencies.json"),
                               Charsets.UTF_8)) {
    json = CharStreams.toString(reader);
}
```